# Returning an index of an element in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

The x is a list and v is an element that is in the list. Need to return the index of that element, v else should return -1.

The code below works fine when the element is in the list but it doesn't return -1 when not found.

The error is `else let j = 1+index t v in j` because it keeps adding 1 and when the empty list is passed it does `total = total - 1` and thus return the index of the very last element.

I am a new OCaml learner, don't know how to solve this issue.

```
let rec index x v = 
  match x with
    [] -> -1
    | h::t -> 
      if h == v then 0
      else let j = 1+ index t v in j
```

Comment: Drive-by comment: _never ever_ use out-of-band sentinel values like -1 in ML. That's what the `option` type is for.

Comment: Please mark answer as correct if you think it is helpful. Asking without marking = no one would help your future question

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can direct say `else 1 + index t v` instead of `else let j ...`

Second, the logic of your code is not wrong as long as the desired element does exist in the list, as you told. You basically keep increasing by one as the iteration continues.

However, it is hard to deal with the case where the element is not in the list, because the previous counting won't be stopped.

To deal with this, it is better to keep the counting in our own hand, so if not find but still in middle of list, then increase the count; if do find, then return the count; if not find and reach the end, then return -1, not the count.

So, the count must be a parameter of our recursive function.

```
let index v l =
  let rec aux c = function
    | [] -> None
    | h::t ->
      if h = v then Some c
      else aux (c+1) t
  in 
  aux 0 l
```

The above logic happens to transform to tail-recursive (which sooner or later you will learn).

p.s., normally you use `h = v` as it is the value check. `h == v` is a physical equality check and normally we don't want that.